# Continuous random variable probability on $(0,1)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, metric-spaces, random-variables

I am confused with the probability of a continuous random variable $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$. We have $P(X=a)=0$ for any $a\in\mathbb R$. However, I'm sure we can't do things like this but I don't know the reasons.

Let $\{r_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ be enumerations of rational numbers in $(0,1)$, We can find $t$ for each $n$ as $P(X=r_n)=0$ so that for fixed large $N$
$$ P\Big(X\in(r_n-t,r_n+t)\Big)\le \dfrac{1}{Nn^2},$$
hence $\displaystyle P\Big(X\in(0,1)\Big)\le P\left(\bigcup_{n\ge 1}\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)\in(r_n-t,r_n+t)\}\right)\le \dfrac{1}{N}\sum_{n\ge 1}\dfrac{1}{n^2}\ll\dfrac{1}{N},$ which is not true.

Comment: the statement fails because $\bigcup_{n\geqslant 1}(r_n-t_n,r_n+t_n)$ is much smaller than $(0,1)$

Comment: To add to above comment, it is very important to realize that $t$ depends on $n$.